# Parse a Text File using Java

Tags: java, android

could you point me to an example where I can find more information about how to parse a text file in Java and extracting a particular String or reg ex out of It.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.bitquill.net/trac/wiki/Android/OCR

Comment: Well Thanks James its a Nice link.. I was unaware of the information it provided.
Nice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Scanner for reading the text file:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Check out StringTokenizer for parsing strings:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Checkout String's split method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Here is some examples,
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42